# MYSQL: How to find player_id from surname?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm now trying to populate my 'testMatch' table (below) with data from my unormalised 'summary' table:

TESTMATCH TABLE

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| match_id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| match_date       | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| ground           | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| homeTeam         | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| awayTeam         | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| matchResult      | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| manOfMatch       | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| homeTeam_captain | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| homeTeam_keeper  | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| awayTeam_captain | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
| awayTeam_keeper  | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       | 
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There is no problem populating match_id -----> manOfMatch - it is 'homeTeam_captain', 'homeTeam_keeper', 'awayTeam_captain' and 'awayTeam_keeper' that i'm having problems bringing in.

SUMMARY TABLE

```
mysql> DESCRIBE SUMMARY;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| matchID         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       | 
| Test            | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| matchDate       | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| Ground          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| HomeTeam        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AwayTeam        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| matchResult     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| MarginRuns      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| MarginWickets   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| ManOfMatch      | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| HomeTeamCaptain | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| HomeTeamKeeper  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AwayTeamCaptain | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AwayTeamKeeper  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to somehow select the data from summary, get the corresponding player_id and input the player_id into my 'testMatch'.  Player table below:

PLAYERS TABLE

```
mysql> describe players;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| player_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| player_surname | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| team           | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So to clarify, eg. I want to select homeTeam_captain data FROM summary table BUT not the name, I want the corresponding player_id instead.

I assume I need to use some sort of join/subqueries to get this done... i've tried selecting with:

```
select matchID, player_id, player_surname, team from players p, summary s
where
s.hometeamcaptain = p.player_surname ORDER BY matchID;
```

but this brings back 73 rows and there should only be 65 (65 matches).

I hope this makes sense and thanks for your help!!
Theresa

Answer (score 1):

Are there overlapping names? If so, also assure that the teams correspond (add `s.HomeTeam = p.team` to the where block). If there are players with the same name in one team, you will have to solve these conflicts manually.

To select *all* the keepers/captains at once, you need [left outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join). I guess it will be one join per player, so you have to join the same table 4 times.

Once you've selected the right data, you can insert it in your `testMatch` table with [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: OK, my query works, but I still don't know how to join/subquery in order to put this query result into my 'matchTest' table?

Thanks
Theresa

Comment: Hi,

I'm afraid the s.HomeTeam = p.team worked for hometeam_captain but not for hometeam_keeper because it returns 61 results and it should be 65.  Sorry for my dense-ness, i'm new to this and have an assignment due on Wed!

Comment: Well, then I guess these keepers aren't in your database...or maybe their names are written slightly different in both tables?! You can select all games from summary and left join the players. Then you see which games have a *NULL* player and see why there is no match.

Comment: Hi Larry,

I've managed to get the query i think i need:
insert into testMatch (match_id, homeTeam_captain)
select matchID, hometeamcaptain=(select players.player_id from players, `summary` where players.player_surname = summary.HomeTeamCaptain and players.team = summary.HomeTeam) 
from summary;
BUT the error says 'RROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row' - I know it returns 65 rows... and i want the 65 rows to be inserted into my table so why won't it let me?  Thanks again

Comment: 'insert into testMatch (match_id, homeTeam_captain)
select matchID, (select players.player_id from players, summary where players.player_surname = summary.HomeTeamCaptain and players.team = summary.HomeTeam) 
AS hometeamcaptain
from summary;'